# PyQt5 QTranslator translate not working with constants file

Tags: python, pyqt5, constants, qtranslator

I am trying to learn pyqt and some mvc pattern stuff. I'd also like to have some translation for my app. Basic experiments worked great, so i tried to implement it within my app, but here i struggle right now.

here is where i initialize QTranslator:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QTranslator
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

from controller.main_controller import MainController


if __name__ == '__main__':
    KodiDBEditor = QApplication(sys.argv)
    translator = QTranslator(KodiDBEditor)
    translator.load("translate/de_DE.qm")
    KodiDBEditor.installTranslator(translator)
    main = MainController()
    sys.exit(KodiDBEditor.exec_())
```

My Controller initializes the view, collecting data from the model:

```
**snip**
    def init_ui(self):
        self.view.setWindowTitle(self.model.get_title())
        self.view.setGeometry(self.model.get_geometry())
        self.view.create_menus(self.model.get_menu())
```

Within my view, i have a function, which creates menus from a dictionary, which itself is a constant from a file constants.py

```
**snip**
    def create_menus(self, menu):
        for i in menu:
            fm = self.menuBar().addMenu(i['label'])
            for j in i['action']:
                if j == '---':
                    fm.addSeparator()
                else:
                    action = QAction()
                    action.setParent(self)
                    action.setText(j['label'])
                    action.setIcon(QIcon.fromTheme(j['icon']))
                    action.setShortcut(j['shortcut'])
                    action.setStatusTip(j['statustip'])
                    fm.addAction(action)
```

constants.py:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
translate = QCoreApplication.translate

MENU = (
    {'label': translate('MainModel', '&File'), 'action': (
        {'label': translate('MainModel','Export'), 'icon': '', 'shortcut': 'Ctrl+B', 'statustip': translate('MainModel','Export Database')},
        '---',
        {'label': 'E&xit', 'icon': 'application-exit', 'shortcut': 'Ctrl+Q', 'statustip': 'Exit Application'}
    )},
    {'label': '&Settings', 'action': (
        {'label': 'KodiDBEditor', 'icon': '', 'shortcut': '', 'statustip': 'Einstellungen für KodiDBEditor'},
    )},
    {'label': '&Hilfe', 'action': (
        {'label': 'Sub1', 'icon': '', 'shortcut': '', 'statustip': 'Sub1'},
        {'label': 'Sub2', 'icon': '', 'shortcut': '', 'statustip': 'Sub2'},
        {'label': 'Sub3', 'icon': '', 'shortcut': '', 'statustip': 'Sub3'}
    )}

)
```

However, the parts in question won't be translated. (I created the ts file, edited it in QT linguist and built the qm file)

If i place some single code like:

```
print(translate('MainModel', '&File'))
```

anywhere in my code, that string is translated correctly
Also, if place the MENU constant straight into my model, everything is fine.
However, i prefer to have the separate constants approach (since there will be more)

So the question is, why doesn't my code translate as it is?

As per request, a simple working example (minimal.py):

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTranslator
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

from other import Main

translate = QCoreApplication.translate

if __name__ == '__main__':
    KodiDBEditor = QApplication(sys.argv)
    translator = QTranslator(KodiDBEditor)
    translator.load("translate/de_DE.qm")
    KodiDBEditor.installTranslator(translator)
    main = Main()
    sys.exit(KodiDBEditor.exec_())
```

(other.py):

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow

from misc.constants import MENU


class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.printstuff()
        self.show()

    def printstuff(self):
        translate = QCoreApplication.translate
        MENU2 = (
            {'label': translate('MainModel', '&File'), 'action': (
                {'label': translate('MainModel', 'Export'), 'icon': '', 'shortcut': 'Ctrl+B',
                 'statustip': translate('MainModel', 'Export Database')},
                '---',
                {'label': 'E&xit', 'icon': 'application-exit', 'shortcut': 'Ctrl+Q', 'statustip': 'Exit Application'}
            )},
            {'label': '&Settings', 'action': (
                {'label': 'KodiDBEditor', 'icon': '', 'shortcut': '', 'statustip': 'Einstellungen für KodiDBEditor'},
            )},
            {'label': '&Hilfe', 'action': (
                {'label': 'Sub1', 'icon': '', 'shortcut': '', 'statustip': 'Sub1'},
                {'label': 'Sub2', 'icon': '', 'shortcut': '', 'statustip': 'Sub2'},
                {'label': 'Sub3', 'icon': '', 'shortcut': '', 'statustip': 'Sub3'}
            )})
        print(MENU)  # tuple holding the menu dicts. strings are not translated, &File = &File
        print(translate('MainModel', '&File'))  # this is working &File = &Datei
        print(MENU2) #this is working as well
```

constants.py as above

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: `get_menu()` returns the variable MENU?

Comment: Yes it does. MENU is stored in self.menu

Answer (score 1):

Ok, seems to be an import problem. If i import Main (which itselfs import MENU) after Qtranslator has been initialized, everything works. So it seems like translate() is executed at import. Is there a way to avoid that? Right now my workaround is to call translate a second time, when the action text is set. Looks a bit hacky, but seems to work.

Comment: It *is* executed at import: `minimal` (or your program, anyway) loads `other`, which loads `constants`; MENU is part of the main scope of `constants`, so it is evaluated as soon as it is imported, meaning that it's automatically translated, but since no translation has been loaded yet, it uses the default english strings. This means that you have to do some refactoring and ensure that the files are imported in the correct way or, at least, that MENU is evaluated only when the translation is actually loaded.